# Set dynamic class based on index in angular ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to set class for elements inside `ngFor` but changes are not reflecting as this class declaration `class="car-title{{index}}"` seems to be not working .

I have given equivalent colors as shown below for car title that needs to be displayed based on the index value inside `ngFor`.

```
                .car-title1 {
                    color: blue;
                }
                 .car-title2 {
                    color: red;
                }
                .car-title3 {
                    color: green;
                }
```

Plunker link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/B1ReKP6i6UpVEewkZetZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

user class binding

```
[class]="'car-title'+(index+1)"
```

Comment: Does the same applies for id as well?

Comment: yep, but don't forget that it sets id/class async. If you want to get element by id in js/ts you will have to write it in correct place

Answer (score 6):

The right way to do this is to use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"

[ngClass]="'car-title'+ i"
```

Answer (score 2):

Works Fine

```
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"

[class]="'car-title'+(i+1)"
```

OR

```
[ngClass]="'car-title'+ i"
```